# CheckBox inside a View inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

Here's my aproach:

I have a custom ListView containing a custom Adapter containing two different kind of Views. One of them has a CheckBox in each View.

I just want to notify the Activity when one of those CheckBoxes have been clicked, and to pass it a boolean: true if ANY of the boxes are checked, false otherwise.

How should I do it?

I just need the theorethical answer, not code.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use OnCheckedChangeListener for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- implement the activity by  checkedChangeListene and override the code in activity

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {

               Object obj = buttonView.getTag();
            // perform logic
        }

    }
```

2- pass the activity in custom adapter constructor.

3- set in getView

```
   CheckBox  chkBx = (CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
    if(null!=chkBx ){
    chkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mActivty);
    chkBx.setTag(position);
   }
```

Comment: Ok, and how do I check WHICH box I checked?. I use a BitSet to keep account of the checked boxes, but I need the position of the view holding the box. onCheckedChanged obviously doesn't implement that. Should I use a custom Listener or something?

Comment: can set the posotion comes in getView as the tag of each CheckBox  as in updated code....

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand that. Could you please explain yourself?

Comment: you need the position in the listview of checkbox clicked, so I set the position with each CheckBox  and in onCheckedChanged you 'll get this CheckBox  and there you can get back that position using tag

Comment: I acomplished what I wanted to do. Thank you very much, your help was very useful!